# Clean approach to achieving Merge functionality in Postgres, for when not matched by target/source

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge

I attempted to use a MERGE statement in Postgres 16.2, and you can find the example below:

```sql
MERGE INTO schema1.target_table AS t
USING schema2.source_table AS s
ON t.id = s.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        data1 = s.data1,
        data2 = s.data2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    INSERT (id, data1, data2,)
    VALUES (s.id, s.data1, s.data2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    DELETE;
```

While trying this query, I discovered that Postgres has supported the MERGE statement since version 15, but it does not support the "BY TARGET" or "BY SOURCE" statement, throwing this error:

```sql
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "BY"
LINE 8: WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
```

In my search for cleaner alternatives to achieve the same result, I came across this [helpful but old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315874/how-to-correct-migrate-merge-statement-with-not-matched-by-target-from-ms-sq). While it worked perfectly, I find it a bit complicated to understand and would prefer to avoid it to keep my code as clean as possible.

Do you know of any way to achieve the same result in a cleaner manner?

Comment: The `by [source|target]` clause is non-standard: it's [Microsoft SQL's extension of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)#Other_non-standard_implementations).

Comment: Why not just truncate the target table and insert the new data?  Or, a merge for the insert and update, and then a separate delete? *(Please be specific as why these common options don't meet your needs, and provide an actual [mre] with example tables with data)*

Comment: The other answer looks clean enough to me. By "clean" do you mean "only one query", or is there something dirty about the other answer that makes it unsuitable to you?

Comment: I didn't specify why the old answer is not clean for me, I would have expected "only one query" as @Bohemian mentioned. As I'm not sure if there is a better approch to that.

Comment: @leadvic That's what transactions are for. Even CTE based "single queries" can have concurrency conditions that make them require transactions and locks. "Single query" should never be an objective in and of itself.

Comment: The original isn't clean. `MERGE` in SQL Server has so many problems that it's almost unclean by definition. [Check this very short list of articles](https://sqlblog.org/merge) and this [very long list of actual bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). t's not atomic, can throw for unexpected reasons and won't be any faster than separate DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT queries - quite the opposite.

Comment: @leadvic the "only one query" attempt is the dirty one - the query engine is called to switch mode (inserting, deleting, updating) on different rows. That's not how query engines work, so the engine will *split* the data into separate operations that will work on the same table and compete for IO. You're lucky you don't try to modify one of the match rows, otherwise those *independent* operations would risk seeing and processing each other's changes. That's why you need either an explicit transaction or HOLDLOCK at the very least.

Comment: @leadvic with these kinds of things, if I get something working and it performs OK, I move on to something else. There are no prizes for beautiful code. Only prizes for stuff that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say what's *not clean* about the [old query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315874/how-to-correct-migrate-merge-statement-with-not-matched-by-target-from-ms-sq), but here's an alternative: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bav_Usbo)

```sql
with cte as (
  delete from schema1.target_table 
  where id not in (select id from schema2.source_table) )
insert into schema1.target_table
table schema2.source_table
on conflict(id) do update set data1=excluded.data1,
                              data2=excluded.data2;
```

The principle remains exactly the same: that's an old-school PostgreSQL [upsert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT), with a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to fill in for the [non-standard `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` extension found in Ms SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)#Other_non-standard_implementations).

In [the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bav_Usbo) you can see there's effectively very little difference between them - if you tweak the sample size and reorder tests, it seems like any advantage of this here over the old one is down to noise. You can tweak both to instead do anti-joins, `except`, `not exists` (also leads to a hashed right anti-join), etc, depending on how your table's actually set up and indexed.

Also, the two operations (delete+upsert) wrapped in a transaction are no different than gluing them together into a single statement, but the 2in1 is certainly cleaner and a bit more convenient to use. Safer if you account for being less prone to bugs related to concurrency.

Demo also shows [@MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/matbailie)'s immediate [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78047815/clean-approach-to-achieving-merge-functionality-in-postgres-for-when-not-matche/78047934#comment137593314_78047815) to `truncate` in a transaction is reliably faster than either of these. Be [warned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caveat_emptor) that [while it's transaction-safe, it's not MVCC-safe](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-truncate.html#id-1.9.3.181.7).

If you decide not to wipe&repopulate the table, you can consider adjusting your [`fillfactor` storage parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR): by default it's `100`, so your updates and inserts go to new pages. Making it `50` makes them half-empty and able to accept new (versions of) rows, in-place. I think the demo got 25% shorter exec times after adding that in.